# Cannot ssh using IP but able to do it using hostname from /etc/hosts

Tags: ssh

I am logged in on a Debian 9 server as a regular user. I am able to ssh into another server using the private key from a directory and hostname from `/etc/hosts` file.

`ssh -i /path/to/id_rsa user@hostname` but if I replace the `hostname` with `IP`, it's asking for the password. Why can I ssh using hostname only?

Comment: Do you have a `~/.ssh/config` file with a section matching the host name?

Comment: Do you have a `~/.ssh/config` file that sets options for the specific host?

Comment: I do not have a config file in `~/.ssh` directory.

Comment: Didn't know /etc/hosts contained private keys! Now I'm a bit confused!

Comment: @MarcusMüller The private key is in a separate directory. The hostname is in `/etc/hosts/`

Comment: Hm. Really confusing! If this is how it is then something is really wrong: a server that had password authentication disabled will not offer the client to send in a password, and the client hence would not ask for one but immediately fail. Sure this is a password for logging in, and not your private Key's encryption phrase?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry I was wrong. `PermitRootLogin` is `prohibit password` but `PasswordAuthentication` is `yes`. Still confused as to why IP address is asking for password but using hostname is logging me in via key.

Comment: Add `-vvv` to get details on exactly what it's doing in each case, and look for what's different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to use hostname because it was configured in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`
The reason I was not able to use IP address because I was specifying the wrong public key. This was discovered using `-vvv` option to the `ssh` command.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)

Comment: Please mark this as an accepted answer.